# How does pricing work if I don't return anything from my webhook

Tags: twilio

```js
app.post('/sms', async (req, res)=> {
    sms_message = req.body.Body
    phoneNumber = req.body.From 

    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message(ret)

    res.type('text/xml')
       .send(twiml.toString()) 
})
```

Do I save money if I decide to not return anything?

For example

```js
app.post('/sms', async (req, res)=> {
    sms_message = req.body.Body
    phoneNumber = req.body.From 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be charged per sent text message, i.e. in the above scenario.

However, please note that Twilio expects that your webhook returns TwiML. However, you can return an empty TwiML response which won't sent a text message:

```js
app.post('/sms', async (req, res)=> {
    sms_message = req.body.Body
    phoneNumber = req.body.From 

    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    res.type('text/xml').send(twiml.toString()) 
})
```